# How can you pass a docstring to a wrapper function in python?

Tags: python

If I have a class that is wrapping another object (let's say Pandas dataframe), how can I pass the docstrings from the wrapped class to the wrapper class?

For example, in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

class DataframeWrapper():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.df.plot(*args, **kwargs)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(0,1, size=(10,2)), columns=['a', 'b'])
wdf1 = DataframeWrapper(df1)
wdf1.plot('a', 'b')
```

How can I get the plot function in the wrapper class to have the same docstring as Pandas plot (so that it can be seen in Jupyter by pressing shift+tab)?

Comment: you can access the doc string using the `__doc__` property on objects. They are writable.

Comment: how can I assign that doc to the wrapper function's plot method?

Comment: `self.plot.__doc__ = df.plot.__doc__ `

Comment: That gives me an error: `AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'method' objects is not writable`. I am adding this line to the end of the constructor.

Comment: hmm.. lemme try this..

Comment: Alright.. my bad.. yeah. method `__doc__`'s aren't writable. Anyway, there are ways around it. The one I just posted below was the first thing I tried. We can look a bit more to see what other options there are.

Comment: To what extent do you need to 'wrap' the dataframe? Are you trying to make a proxy that dynamically gives access to the hosted dataframe's attributes/methods as needed (generating wrappers)? What's this going to be used for? I have some ideas, but it gets complicated...

Answer (score 2):

Alright.. putting this here so you can see the hackish idea I had.. it seems to work, but don't know if it's all that pretty... here it is...

```
>>> class DataframeWrapper():
...     def __init__(self, df):
...         self.df = df
...         
...         @functools.wraps(df.plot)
...         def _plot(*args, **kwargs):
...             return df.plot(*args, **kwargs)
...             
...         self.plot = _plot
```

Trying it out in my shell, a huge doc string box fills my screen.. This is about as good as a method declared the other way.. you have access to `self` within it as well as the hosted dataframe.

This basically does the same thing a decorator does. You could just declare functions for each dataframe method you're interested in and assign them to attributes within `__init__()`.

Taking it a step further we could create a decorator style function.

```
>>> def dfwrap(method):
...     @functools.wraps(method)
...     def _dfwrap(*args, **kwargs):
...         # Do some extra stuff here...
...         return method(*args, **kwargs)
...     return _dfwrap
```

Then in `__init__()`:

```
...     self.foo = dfwrap(df.foo)
...     self.bar = dfwrap(df.bar)
...     self.baz = dfwrap(df.baz)
```